# Accessing items in a web directory which is not directly accessible

Tags: website, screen-scraping

E.g., I want to download an image of each of the US state trees. I find Alabama's longleaf pine at:

https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/primary-images/longleafpine.jpg

More generally, all of these US state tree images live in:

https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/primary-images/

Now, if I could access this web directory directly, I could just use DownloadThemAll to download all these images. But I cannot access that web directory directly. I just get a "Page not found" message.

So, how can I download all 50 images *from this site* without having to manually click through each of the 50 states?

**EDIT**: This is just a small example of a general problem I have. So, context-specific solutions (e.g., go to this *other* site with all 50 images available for direct download) don't actually work for me.

Comment: By going to a site that **does* let you access all items at once, e.g., https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._state_trees

Comment: I edited my question to reflect that suggestions such as yours don't work for me. I'm curious about the general case.

Comment: Have you tried jDownloader?

Comment: There are website "rippers", "crawlers", etc. that can do what you describe, but they might bring in a *lot* of extraneous info, i.e., everything on the website, unless you can create a regex to restrict it to just images. A commercial one is at https://prowebscraper.com/blog/top-website-ripper-or-website-downloader-compared/ , also see https://www.octoparse.com/blog/4-best-easy-to-use-website-ripper . That said, I rarely want *everything* on a site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not have access to the directory there isn't a way to know the filenames of the pictures within it very easily. This creates a lot of extra work for you. This means you need to use software that can brute force the files if you can't get all the filenames (not the easiest to set up/user-friendly). Using something like `dirbuster` you can either brute force for the names of the files in the `primary-images` directory.

Though it is important to note that **this is frowned upon**. Using software like this and what others are suggesting creates a lot of extra traffic to the server since you are sending a request for the page whether or not it exists. This can easily get your IP blocked by the server administrator/firewall for slowing down service for others or be identified as a [DOS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) if you're sending a lot. Use if you know what you're doing & have permission to be all above board.

Your best bet would be to either click through all of them, or if you can get all the names of the files you can make a simple `.txt` file with the name of each file delimited by a new line:

```
 longleafpine.png
 shortbarkpine.jpeg
 bigtree2.png
 ...
```

And you can use this little piece of Python code I wrote for this function ([download on GitHub](https://github.com/nazklx/stackfileshare/blob/main/imgdl.py)):

```
# Create an empty folder and put only the .txt wordlist and this .py script in it.
# All the images will be saved in this directory.

import requests
import shutil

url = input('Enter URL: ')

with open(input('Enter wordlist filename: ')) as wordlist:
    for line in wordlist:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        filepath = url+line
        img = requests.get(filepath, stream=True)
        if img.status_code == 200:
            with open(line, 'wb') as newfile:
                shutil.copyfileobj(img.raw, newfile)
            print('Successfully downloaded ' + filepath)
        else:
            print('Failed to download ' + filepath)
```

Here is a screenshot of it running:

[image: Image of script working]

If it's your first time using Python follow [this guide to install](https://realpython.com/installing-python/#how-to-install-python-on-windows) and use the `cd` command in the command prompt to be in the same directory as the python script. For example, if the script was in your documents folder you would run `cd C:\Users\$User\Documents\`, then run `python imgdl.py`, & follow the prompts.